# Adicionar miniatura de imagem e switch toggle em tabela

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, boot

Olá, pessoal. Sigo a minha saga de editar um template boostrap,com muito aprendizado porém com muita cabeça batida na parede rs. Gostaria de saber como adicionar uma miniatura de imagem nessa tabela do meu site, nos itens da coluna "nome do produto", todas as vezes em que tentei a imagem caga a tabela toda kk. Além disso, gostaria de adicionar um switch toggle bottom de "sim e não" na coluna "aceito", porém toda vez em que insiro o código aparece apenas um checkbox normal. Link do meu site: http://tratspay.com/app/co-producoes.html

```
<!-- Main content -->
<div class="content">
  <div class="info-box">

    <p>Abaixo você pode ver em quais produtos você recebe algum valor de co-produçções e pode inclusive aceitar ou recusar pedidos relacionados a isso.</p>
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>

            <th scope="col">Nome do Produto</th>
            <th scope="col">Data Limite</th>
            <th scope="col">Tipo</th>
            <th scope="col">Comissão</th>
            <th scope="col">Aceito</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>

            <td>Produto A</td>
            <td>12/12/12</td>
            <td>Co-Produtor</td>
            <td>5%</td>
            <td> Sim </td> 
          </tr>
          <tr>

           <td>Produto A</td>
            <td>12/12/12</td>
            <td>Co-Produtor</td>
            <td>5%</td>
            <td> Sim </td> 
          </tr>
          <tr>

           <td>Produto A</td>
            <td>12/12/12</td>
            <td>Co-Produtor</td>
            <td>5%</td>
            <td> Sim </td> 
          </tr>
          <tr>

          <td>Produto A</td>
            <td>12/12/12</td>
            <td>Co-Produtor</td>
            <td>5%</td>
            <td> Sim </td> 
          </tr>
          <tr>

           <td>Produto A</td>
            <td>12/12/12</td>
            <td>Co-Produtor</td>
            <td>5%</td>
            <td> Sim </td> 
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.content -->
```

Comment: Qual o problema com a imagem na tabela? testei aqui e deu certinho...  olha ia o link http://prntscr.com/mri9qv  Sobre o Checkbox acredito que vc está copiando o código de algum lugar, mas não está sabendo usar da forma correta. Acho que vc deveria dividir a pergunta em duas, primeiro tenta focar na imagem e qual é o problema. Depois vc posta a tabela já com a imagem e pergunta sobre o Switch

Comment: Como você fez? Aqui não consigo dimensionar o tamanho da imagem dentro da coluna. Peço desculpas desde já se estiver fazendo alguma pergunta besta kk.

Comment: A imagem consegui colocar aqui, era bobeira minha, falta de atenção rs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue o modelo. Basta definir no css um `Width` e deixa o `height` no auto que facilita, ou então coloca as duas medidas na mão...

Sobre o `Toggle` vc deve está deixando de colocar alguma coisa... Eu simulei usando um `Button` do próprio Bootstrap que vc está usando e não deu problema...

```css
img {
  width: 50px;
  height: auto;
}
.table td, .table th {
    vertical-align: middle !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://tratspay.com/app/dist/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://tratspay.com/app/dist/css/style.css" />


  <!-- Main content -->
  <div class="content">
    <div class="info-box">

      <p>Abaixo você pode ver em quais produtos você recebe algum valor de co-produçções e pode inclusive aceitar ou
        recusar pedidos relacionados a isso.</p>
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>

              <th scope="col">Nome do Produto</th>
              <th scope="col">Data Limite</th>
              <th scope="col">Tipo</th>
              <th scope="col">Comissão</th>
              <th scope="col">Aceito</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>

              <td>
                <img src="https://placecage.com/100/100">
                Produto A
              </td>
              <td>12/12/12</td>
              <td>Co-Produtor</td>
              <td>5%</td>
              <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
                  Single toggle
                </button>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

              <td>Produto A</td>
              <td>12/12/12</td>
              <td>Co-Produtor</td>
              <td>5%</td>
              <td> Sim </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

              <td>Produto A</td>
              <td>12/12/12</td>
              <td>Co-Produtor</td>
              <td>5%</td>
              <td> Sim </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

              <td>Produto A</td>
              <td>12/12/12</td>
              <td>Co-Produtor</td>
              <td>5%</td>
              <td> Sim </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

              <td>Produto A</td>
              <td>12/12/12</td>
              <td>Co-Produtor</td>
              <td>5%</td>
              <td> Sim </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.content -->
```

Comment: Muuito obrigado pela força @hugocsl. Valeu mesmo, a toogle eu consegui colocar também com a tua ajuda.

Comment: @IgorRosa sem problemas meu amigo que bom que resolveu!